# Building a distributable static library that uses cocoapods

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, cocoapods

I'm building a static library to be distributed to other iOS developers and having some trouble configuring the linker to allow the static library to be used in another app.  I have used [this guide](http://longtrieuquang.wordpress.com/2013/04/29/how-to-build-custom-ios-framework-with-xcode/) to create a MyStaticLibrary.framework bundle containing the lib itself, and other assets such as images.  This builds successfully and uses cocoapods to source the required dependencies (AFNetworking, etc.).  So far, so good.

But when I import MyStaticLibrary.framework into a new Xcode project to test build an app with the library, I get tons of linker errors (Undefined symbols for architecture i386, _OBJC_CLASS_$_CLASSNAME) indicating that I'm doing something very wrong here.

So my question is, how can I build MyStaticLibrary.framework with the dependencies sourced from cocoapods, such that I can provide a 3rd party with just my framework file and allow them access to all functions specified in the public headers?

Comment: Check in your project's build settings, under 'Framework Search Paths', it should include the directory that your .framework is contained in. Without this setting, the linker cannot find your static binary

Comment: @michaels The directory with the framework is included in the search paths.  This is not the issue I'm having, as Xcode is finding the headers from my framework (ie: it compiles fine, it just fails at the link stage)  The issue seems to be that any files that are linked against when building the framework also need to be linked against when building the test app that imports the framework.  However, those files are not included in the framework and I don't know how to include them.

Comment: Finding the headers and finding the binary are different things, and they require different build settings. But I think I understand the problem a bit better now - you're linking to third party libraries that are not compiled into your binary?

Comment: @michaels That's correct, and some of those 3rd party libraries are distributed via cocoapods. In addition, some of these 3rd party libraries I have the source files for but others are static libraries of their own.  I would like to compile all of these into my binary but I'm not sure how to configure my static library target to accomplish this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any libraries you include using CocoaPods will **not** be compiled into your framework by default - they're meant to be external dependencies that are not part of your actual product. However, according to their FAQ, they support a mode where you can download pods and *not* have them linked to your project. From their FAQ:

> Note that CocoaPods itself does not require the use of a workspace. If
>   you prefer to use sub-projects, you can do so by running pod install
>   --no-integrate, which will leave integration into your project up to you as you see fit.

To include external dependencies in your compiled binary:

- For code: Instead of using cocoapods, check out the repositories you want to include and copy the source files into your project -- this will ensure they are compiled with the rest of your code
- For static libraries (i.e. `.a` files), in your framework's `Link Binary With Libraries` build phase, make sure to include all the ones you would like to compile. You should also make sure the associated header files are included in `Copy Headers` build phase, with the appropriate visibility.

**Note** When bundling third party libraries in this way, you run the risk of conflicting with the projects that are integrating your framework. For example, let's say you are using a lib called `SOSomeView`, and you choose to compile that in with your framework. Now, if the app you are integrating with also includes `SOSomeView`, you will get a compile-time error that the class is declared twice. To fix this issue, you should re-namespace any external dependencies you want to hardcode into your framework (i.e. rename the class to `XXSOSomeView`).

I don't know how to solve that problem if you are compiling static libraries in with your framework.

Comment: The first bullet point is an approach I'm very comfortable with, as I use it all the time. The second one I'm not too familiar with, but I was able to create a working proof-of-concept using the [OCMock](http://ocmock.org/) static library, so it definitely can be done in this way

Comment: Is there no way to configure the target so that cocoapods-sourced dependencies are compiled into the framework? I disagree with your assessment that this goes against the purpose of cocoapods.  It doesn't make sense to force the end user to source dependencies that aren't even visible to them (and it violates the requirements of the framework, one of which is to provide a simple, self-contained library to the end user) It also doesn't make sense to store all of these dependencies in the repository for the framework. If I must, I will store the dependencies in the repo, but would prefer not.

Comment: You're right, CocoaPods does support "no-frills" usage where it will download pods for you, but leave the integration up to you. Check out the [FAQ](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/faq.html) "CocoaPods uses workspaces, which are considered user data. Why does it not use normal sub-projects?"

Comment: I have selected this as the correct answer, though if anyone knows how to accomplish this via the standard cocoapods workspace setup I would still be interested in how to configure that.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `Link Binary With Libraries`! I haven't run across that answer anywhere else. (This helped me even though I don't have the same problem as OP; I just wanted to create a static library that included CocoaPods)

Comment: @stackunderflow Did you solve this problem as the way you want? or did you follow the michaels' way?