# iOS internal podspec installation not installing external Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm writing an iOS library which use external libraries like Restkit. Everything works fine in my lib but when I import it in an other project using Pods, only my sources are imported. Which means I don't have external dependencies like Restkit.

I added in my podspec file : s.dependency 'Restkit' '~> 0.24.0'

But I see no difference. I've the feeling I'm missing something, can someone help me ?

Regards

**EDIT**

SDK podspec file (important parts):

```
# ――― Source Location ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #

s.source       = { :git => "***************.git", :tag => "0.0.1" }

# ――― Source Code ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #

s.source_files  = "bee-ios-sdk/sdk", "bee-ios-sdk/sdk/**/*.{h,m}"
s.exclude_files = "bee-ios-sdk/sdk/Exclude"

# s.public_header_files = "Classes/**/*.h" # Maybe this ?

# ――― Project Settings ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #

# s.requires_arc = true

# s.xcconfig = { "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2" }
s.dependency 'RestKit', '~> 0.24.0'
s.dependency 'CocoaSecurity'
```

And my Podfile inside my app

```
target 'bee' do
    pod 'bee-ios-sdk' # Private pod repository containing the podspec above
end
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT 2**

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing bee-ios-sdk (0.0.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

And as you can see, I only have my sources. No trace of RestKit and others which leads me to 'RestKit/RestKit.h' file not found error when I'm trying to build. Adding all my SDK dependencies inside my App podfile fixes the problem but that's clearly not sexy..
[image: Pods directory]

There is no source 'github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' to the top of my podfile ?
Right now, my podfile (app) requests a private git repo with .podspec file inside containing the url of my sdk. I followed this [tutorial](http://albertodebortoli.github.io/blog/2014/03/11/cocoapods-working-with-internal-pods/) to do it.

Comment: you might need to include your podspec file and your podfile

Comment: @DanielGalasko Can you develop what you mean ? Where / how am I supposed to include those files ?

All I have in my App Podfile is something like pod 'mySDK' and running pod install download .h/m files but none of the dependencies declared inside my SDK Podfile.

Comment: Yes but you wrote a custom podspec so why not include it in the post? @MajorShepard

Comment: Added some information, if you need more, I'll keep digging

Comment: Thats much better! Would you also be able to list whats inside the Pods directory in the file navigator of Xcode. Just trying to understand what leads you to believe the dependencies are missing

Comment: Its odd that a pod install would work if the dependencies failed. I'm sure you added source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
 to the top of your podfile as well?

Comment: try run a pod instal --verbose to see if those dependencies come up as warnings maybe. just to confirm, at the top of your profile you should have two sources? One being your internal specs repo and the other being 'github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

Comment: This is driving me crazy... At first, I had a no 'sources' inside my podfile BUT it was working (more or less). Now that I've tried to put CocoaPods & internal git repo in source, I've got [!] An unexpected version directory `build` was encountered... Note that 'pod repo' gives me 2 repo, internal & cocoapods. I should probably re-try from scratch and update my topic after

Comment: You manage to resolve it?

Comment: Not yet.. Since my sdk has no vocation to be shared, I decided to create a directory with .a file and headers seems to be a better solution - (see: http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/). But even if I put every generated .a (mine and .a from other dependencies) I still have the 'RestKit/RestKit.h' file not found because I import them inside my headers. Solution should be simple but I don't have it and I'm not familiar with Xcode configuration yet :(

Comment: I'm really keen to help you cos i faced the exact same problem! And i went about trying that solution but ended up getting it working, let me see if I can post a good answer for you just give me a sec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have built several internal libraries using Cocoapods and whilst I cannot immediately understand exactly why you are unable to get the dependencies right I thought it might be a good idea to outline how I do it.

At a broad overview, a typical installation (from scratch) has the following steps:

1. Install cocopods to your machine (`sudo gem install cocoapods`)
2. Setup a private repository that will house all your cocoapods.
3. Create a new pod spec
4. Run the linter and then push your spec to the repo

Step 1 is easy so lets start with 2:

### Setup a private repository that will house all your cocoapods

You should have push access to a git location that will house your pods. Once this repo has been setup you can add it to your installation:

```
pod repo add internalpods 'github.com/private-cocoapodsspecs.git'
```

Naturally I have put in a bogus git url

### Create your first spec

Creating a spec is easy:

```
pod spec create SPEC_NAME
```

where SPEC_NAME is what you want your spec to be called

I won't go to in to detail here because your spec seems good to me. However, what I try and do is always put an Example project inside the repository that you checkout for the spec. One great feature of cocoapods is that you can reference specs locally. So say we writing AFNetworking, the file structure in git might look like this:

```
AFNetworking
     .git
     AFNetworking.podspec
     AFNetworking/ 
          (All the classes we want in our pods)
     ExampleProject/ 
          (Example project that will use the spec locally)
          podfile
```

In the Example Project's podfile we could do something like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' #include this if you will be referencing any public pods!
source 'github.com/private-cocoapodsspecs.git' #our internal repo which we don't need yet
pod 'AFNetworking', :path => '..'
```

This lets you pick up whether there are any issues with your pod before running any installs or pushing to your server so I'm a big fan of this approach. It also lets you develop your pod and have a nice example project that you can always open to make changes or test new features to your pod.

Running a `pod install` in your example project should get you up and running with your pod and all dependencies. Don't forget you can always add the `--verbose` to the install.

Now it's time to send your goodness to the remote:

### Lint and push

The linter will validate your spec to make sure its all ready for pushing (note how I included the source url for our internal remote):

```
pod spec lint --sources=github.com/private-cocoapodsspecs.git,https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git --verbose
```

If thats all great you can go ahead and push. I generally like to allow warnings when doing this because our internal pods don't have licenses and everything falls apart if you try and push without a license:

```
pod repo push internalpods SPEC_NAME.podspec --allow-warnings --verbose
```

see how i used the internalpods name we setup in step 1.

Hopefully that should be enough to help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations ! Everything is working and now I understand how it really works ! 

Again, thank you ! :)

Comment: @MajorShepard Thats awesome news! All the best!

Answer (score 2):

CocoaPods is a great and very simple to use tool. Most of time you don't want to import it's generated project manually.

To add Pods dependencies to your project you need:

- Ensure you have the latest version of pod, in terminal run: `sudo gem install cocoapods`
- Create file called "Podfile" (without extension) in your project directory near your .xcodeproj file.
- Edit "Podfile" and add this line to it:
  `pod 'Restkit', '~> 0.24.0'`. For more options please take a look on [CocoaPods Guide page](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html)
- Save file
- Close Xcode if it is still open
- Open terminal and cd to your project's directory (where "Podfile" is located)
- Run `pod install`.

This command will download dependencies and create .xcworkspace file near your .xcodeproj . After it finishes running - be sure to open **.xcworkspace** file.

Now you should be able to see new project called Pods in your workspace - this is where all your dependencies being build and added to your main project: [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/34i4c4hq7znne34/Screenshot%202015-01-12%2013.30.26.png?dl=0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I've done in my sdk library and it's working perfectly.

But, when I want to use this library (which I import as a Pod in my other project), dependency I've put in it (sdk) aren't downloaded :/ This is where I'm stuck

Comment: If you want to add pods to your own framework - take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22872292/983914